# Как сделать реакцию бота на лайк на любую публикацию в сообществе, где он находится Vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api

У меня есть python скрипт с ботом вк(vk_api). Есть вопрос - как сделать так, чтобы при выставлении лайка на публикацию, срабатывало условие? Например:

```
if ...:
   print("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token="TOKEN") 

longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, group_id = "GROUP_ID")

while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen(): #слушаем события в лонгполле
        if event.type == "like_add": # "like_add" - тип события лайка
            print("test")
```